# Create new vm in an existing cloud service (no answer)

Tags: azure

Almost two years ago I created two vm inside a cloud service. Now I would like to add a new one but the azure dashboard has changed since then and I cannot figure out how to put the new vm in the existing cloud service.

I searched in internet and found [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-connect-virtual-machine/): unfortunately the form I have to fill is different (it is the new version) from that in the article and I cannot choose the cloud service. I know there are some powershell commands to move vm between cloud services but I would like to avoid them because I have absolutely no experience. How can I do ?

**UPDATE**:

The only answer to this question does not apply any more as of year 2018, as it is now redirecting to the new https://portal.azure.com/. So basically there isn't any answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still do that in the 'old' portal at http://manage.windowsazure.com. It's right there at the third step of creating a new VM.